# How to change the default outlook data file name when creating a POP3 email account

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

On a Windows 10 PC in my office, every time when I create POP3 email account in Outlook, the name of pst data file automatically created always consists of the email address followed by a fixed person name, e.g. "persona@mycompany.com - Betty.pst", "personb@mycompany.com - Betty.pst", etc.  Could anyone let me know how could I change this strange behavior, i.e. only use the email address but not the person name?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests, the data file’s name is based on your profile’s name when you created.

You can modify the profile's name to change the pst file's name, but seems Outlook doesn't allow you to modify the profile's name.

You need to go Registry to change it. Or you could copy the file and rename it. Then remove the old one.

Refer to the below documents for your reference:

- [Renaming an Outlook Profile](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/renaming-outlook-profile-70020.html)
- [How to rename the profile in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1748-outlook-change-profile-name.html)

But I still suggest you to create the profile’s name with user’s name. The profile's name makes you to select the profile more easily.

Check below screenshots.

Create profile with name workspace

[image: Create profile with name workspace]

File name

[image: File name]

You could follow below steps to turn Outlook's profile prompt on to select or create new profiles easily.

1. From the Mail app in Control Panel, select Show Profiles.
2. Under When starting Microsoft Outlook, use this profile, click Prompt for a profile to be used to  turn Outlook's profile prompt.

Select show profiles

[image: Select show profiles]

Prompt

[image: Prompt]

Comment: Thanks.  I found that when you start running Outlook the first time (e.g. after a new Windows user account was created), a new profile is created using the Windows user name.  My situation is, I believe, the Windows account user name was changed due to change of personnel but the profile name remains unchanged.

BTW, although Windows 10 let you change the username, the underlying home folder name remains unchanged.  Is there any way to change it as well?  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To change the display name of pst-files belonging to POP3 accounts or other archives:

- Open your Account Settings dialog :
  *File > Account Settings > Account Settings…*
- Select tab Data Files
- Double click the pst-file for which you want to change the display name
- Change the Name field
- Press OK twice.

You could also rename the Filename.

Comment: I could change the name but not the file name.

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook 2016 / 365 (fairly common now), you may need to go to Control Panel to get all the options for POP3 Email.

Default Outlook automatic setup does not allow for POP3 email.

Go to Control Panel, click on Mail (Microsoft Outlook). Step 1 below.

A dialogue box opens with Email Accounts, Data Files and Profiles (Step 2 below).

Click on the Data Files tab  (Step 3 below).  Then you can double click and change the name.

You can set up an Email Account in the Accounts tab.  Make sure you do NOT use the Wizard (set up manually).  Then during that process, you can also establish the Account Name and File name.

[image: Outlook 365 Account name management]

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate how I could specify the file name when setting up an email account on the Accounts tab?
What I do now is: before setting up an email account I can add a new data file on the Data Files tab. Then when I setup email account I can use an existing file instead of letting Outlook create a new file.  But this is cumbersome.  
What I also want to solve is: why does the file name created by Outlook not only consists of email address but followed by a specific word (a person name).

Thanks again

Comment: You should be able to specify a new Outlook file when setting up an email account.  I usually use Outlook or some variation. I am am not using the Wizard when I do this.  However I have not used an email address as a file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it "Account settings" -> Change and specify "Your Name":

[image]

[How to change your Microsoft account display name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/search?query=how%20to%20change%20the%20name%20on%20my%20outlook%20email#:%7E:text=In%20Outlook%2C%20choose%20File%20%3E%20Account,update%20the%20Your%20name%20field.)

> In Outlook, choose File > Account Settings > Account Settings. Select the email account that you want to change, and then choose Change. You can change your name on the Account Settings screen. To change the name that displays when you send email, update the Your name field.